# AWS S3 Object deleting issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The object of s3 is:

```
images/jkå^ååö¨..ö &#xf7;aq<aa<2a<qa2.jpg
```

While I delete it from S3 management console it said 100% success but while I the object is still there.

I have tried command line and try to delete it from EC2 instance with the command and that does not work either

My command is:

```
aws s3 rm s3://sws-bucket/images/jkå^ååö¨..ö &#xf7;aq<aa<2a<qa2.jpg
```

Which works for another object.

eg: `aws s3 rm s3://sws-bucket/images/test.jpg`

Working fine.

I really want to delete the object with the special character but can't succeed. Anyone can help with this?

Comment: While I post the question the name of the file has been changed something else this is even strange here the name of the object is :

jkå^ååö¨..ö &#xf7;aq<aa<2a<qa2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution:

While I was checking in the regional file the name was 
'jkå^ååö¨..ö  ÷aq

So when I ran the command

s3://sws-bucket/image/'jkå^ååö¨..ö  ÷aq